# only supported for constants and CTE error in click house

Tags: clickhouse

I encounteerd this error in clickhouse:
sadf
Resolve identifier 'locality' from parent scope only supported for constants and CTE. Actual
default.peoples.locality node type COLUMN.

the query is:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT arrayDistinct(groupArray(zipcode))
    FROM mapping
    WHERE has(city_list, lower(locality))
) AS zip_list
FROM peoples
LIMIT 10
```

SETTINGS allow_experimental_analyzer = 1

like this question https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6932
but I can't rewrite my query to join query, because `has` can't in `join in`, what should I do?

related link: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6697

thanks.